# 1 normal distribution problem

Tags: normal-distribution

It is known that the diameter of a fig-tree is normally distributed with $\mu=50$ cm, $\sigma=12$ cm.

$(1)$ What is the prob, that a randomly selected fig-tree has diameter $>73cm$?

$(2)$ what proportion of fig-trees have a diameter between 40 and 55 cm?

$(3)$ Find the diameter $d$, such that the $30\%$ of the fig trees exceeds the diameter $d$.

Here is what I tried:

So $1$. $\mathbb P(X>73)= \frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{73}^{\infty} e^-{\frac{(x-50)^2}{2\times 144}}$ , right? But I am not able to perform next few steps of this integration to get the final answer, could someone direct me some easy and quick way if exists?

$2.$ $\mathbb P(40<X<55)= \frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{40}^{55} e^-{\frac{(x-50)^2}{2\times 144}}$ , right? But I am not able to perform next few steps of this integration to get the final answer, could someone direct me some easy and quick way if exists?

$3.$ I absolutely do not understand the question so far, Thanks for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a chart of the normal distribution $N(0, 1)$ you should consider that you can use those values to solve your problem, cause in general computing this kind of integrals is complicated.

As you dont have that distribution, you will have to get it "normalized". That means you define $Y = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ so that $Y$ is just $N(0, 1)$, and then you use that $$P(X > 73) = P\biggr(\frac{X-50}{12}>\frac{73-50}{12}\biggr) = P\biggr(Y>0.12166...\biggr) = 1 - P\biggr(Y \leq 0.12166...\biggr)$$
and as i said, those probabilities are all around the internet and books. For doing the second one you will just apply this. I barely understand the 3) too.

The trick is that knowing probabilities on $N(0, 1)$ we are able to just "translate" our distribution and get normalized for all values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int e^{-kx^2}$ can only be calculated numerically. Look up normal tables (or statistics library of your favourite programming language)!